# Is it possible to execute FIO in background and check it's status?

Tags: linux, storage

Is it possible to execute FIO in background and check it's status?

I see there is a server mode and --daemonize, but I am not sure how to check the status of an ongoing FIO job.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to execute FIO in background and check it's status?

Yes (but maybe we're looking at the problem differently). [--daemonize](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-daemonize) backgrounds the *server* portion of fio. The server gets told the I/O to perform from the *client* portion of fio and you're presumably not putting the client into the background (?) so it there should be no impact on your ability to analyse `stdio` of the client to work out the state of the job.

It sounds like you would also be interested in [--status-interval](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-status-interval) and [--output-format=json](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-output-format) ([fio's human output is not meant for machine scraping](https://superuser.com/a/1512572/265087) as illustrated by the [Benchmarking gone wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm1GJMp0QN4#t=17m48s) Surge 2013 lightning talk by Brendan Gregg).